# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B will not read SD Card

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, media-server, act

I have a new Raspberry Pi 3 and wanted to download OMV onto it, however, I can not get the Pi to read my SD card.

I have two different SD cards that I have tried but the ACT light never turns on.

Here is what I have been doing:

1. Get the [image](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openmediavault/files/Raspberry%20Pi%20images/):
2. Use Etcher to Flash ( I have also tried win32DiskImager)
3. Plug the SD card into Pi
4. No ACT light

Am I missing something? I don't understand why it will not read the card.

Comment: Please check against the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Answer (score 0):

you can connect raspberry with HDMI to TV , and see the what happend
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2Tfajsd_Jk